# dtreevizを日本語表記にする際、クラス名だけが文字化けしてしまう

Tags: python, matplotlib, 文字化け, dtreeviz

dtreevizで日本語のデータを扱いたいのですが、クラス名だけが豆腐になってしまいます。
解決策をご存じでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

**環境:**
google colab

#### 手順&コード

①フォントの導入＆キャッシュ削除

```
!apt-get -y install fonts-ipafont-gothic
!ls /root/.cache/matplotlib
!rm -r /root/.cache/matplotlib
```

②ここでランタイムを再起動
③dtreevizで可視化

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
from dtreeviz.trees import dtreeviz

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2)
iris = load_iris()
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

iris.feature_names = ['sepal 縦 (cm)',
 'sepal 横 (cm)',
 'petal 縦 (cm)',
 'petal 横 (cm)']

iris.target_name = ['setosa_セトーサ',
 'versicolor_バーシカラー',
 'virginica_バージニア']

viz = dtreeviz(
    clf,
    iris.data, 
    iris.target,
    target_name='variety',
    feature_names=iris.feature_names,
    class_names=iris.target_name ,
    fontname='IPAPGothic'
) 

display(viz)
```

[image: 出力画像]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

原因は [dtreeviz/trees.py](https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz/blob/master/dtreeviz/trees.py#L1061) で `draw_pichart()` 呼び出しの際に `fontname` を指定していないからです(デフォルトの `Arial` フォントが使用される事になります)。

以下は `fontname` の指定を追加する差分コードになります。

```
$ diff -u trees.py.org trees.py
--- trees.py.org    2021-02-22 12:42:23.000000000 +0900
+++ trees.py    2021-02-22 17:43:04.221405758 +0900
@@ -825,7 +825,7 @@
         if shadow_tree.is_classifier():
             class_leaf_viz(node, colors=color_values,
                            filename=f"{tmp}/leaf{node.id}_{os.getpid()}.svg",
-                           graph_colors=colors)
+                           graph_colors=colors, fontname=fontname)
             leaves.append(class_leaf_node(node))
         else:
             # for now, always gen leaf
@@ -1042,7 +1042,8 @@
 def class_leaf_viz(node: ShadowDecTreeNode,
                    colors: List[str],
                    filename: str,
-                   graph_colors=None):
+                   graph_colors=None,
+                   fontname: str = "Arial"):
     graph_colors = adjust_colors(graph_colors)
     # size = prop_size(node.nsamples(), counts=node.shadow_tree.leaf_sample_counts(),
     #                  output_range=(.2, 1.5))
@@ -1059,7 +1060,7 @@
     counts = node.class_counts()
     prediction = node.prediction_name()
     draw_piechart(counts, size=size, colors=colors, filename=filename, label=f"n={nsamples}\n{prediction}",
-                  graph_colors=graph_colors)
+                  graph_colors=graph_colors, fontname=fontname)
```

[image: 実行結果]

※ Issue として報告しておくとよいかもしれません。

Comment: 解決しました！ありがとうございました！
（2年越しに気づきました。。。御礼なく放置することになり申し訳ございません）